# Show hidden field on option click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form inside this form i have a select tag  with multiple options check it out:

```
<select class="form-control" name="footerLayout">
    <option value="1">1 column</option>
</select>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when i click on a certain field a certain div will show. In this case if i click on field one it should show me the hidden div.

Look how i tried it:

```
$('[name=footerLayout]').click(function() {
    $(".column-1").toggle("slow");
});
```

when I click on `footerLayout` option 1 it should show me the `.column-1` class which is hidden. I know this is wrong but this is what i got so far.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that'd be awesome.

Comment: Is that typo error `slow` ? it should be show.

Comment: it will toggle the element slowly @BharatPatidar

Comment: Interesting, a question in my question ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected value as using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), create a valid selector by string concatenation and use perform the desired operation. As you need to display the hidden `div`, you need to use [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

```
$('[name=footerLayout]').change(function() {
    var selector = ".column-" + $(this).val();
    $(selector).show();
});
```

---

As per comment *in the future i want if you click option 2 to show a hidden div named `.column-2`*

I would recommend, you to use a common class with all the columns like `column`, then you can use [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)  with [Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
$('[name=footerLayout]').change(function() {        
    var selector = ".column-" + $(this).val(); //Create selector        
    $(".column").not(selector).hide(); //Hide others        
    $(selector).show();//Show column based on selected value
});
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('[name=footerLayout]').change(function() {
    var selector = ".column-" + $(this).val(); //Create selector        
    $(".column").not(selector).hide(); //Hide others        
    $(selector).show(); //Show column based on selected value
  });
});
```

```css
.column{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="footerLayout">
  <option value="1">1 column</option>
  <option value="2">2 column</option>
</select>

<div class="column column-1">div 1</div>
<div class="column column-2">div 2</div>
```

Comment: i did this, but when i click on option 1 it doesnt show the hidden div named "column-1"

Comment: in the future i want if you click option 2 to show a hidden div named .column-2

Comment: @KevinAartsen, Updated answer and I am confused with previous comment _when i click on option 1 it doesnt show the hidden div named "column-1"_, If its working delete(always non useful) the comment

Comment: Thanks for your time and sorry for the confussion but here's what happens on mine https://jsfiddle.net/6zzrczhL/

Comment: @KevinAartsen https://jsfiddle.net/mk425srx/ noitce `<div class="column column-1">` and `<div class="column column-2">`, I have added the class `column` so that I can hide all `column`

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like so, It shows the corresponding div when clicking on the appropriate option:

```
    <style>
        div {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <select class="form-control" name="footerLayout">
        <option value="1">1 column</option>
        <option value="2">2 column</option>
        <option value="3">3 column</option>
    </select>

    <div class="div1">div 1</div>
    <div class="div2">div 2</div>
    <div class="div3">div 3</div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("option").click(function(){
            var num = $(this).val();
            $('.div' + num).show();
        });
    </script>
```