# jQuery click event on Select element not working as desired on Chrome 54

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have this code:

HTML

```
 <select class="form-control" name="footerLayout">

      <option value="">
      </option>
      <option value="1">
        1 column
      </option>
      <option value="2">
        2 column
      </option>

    </select>


    <div class="column column-1">
      <h3>Content</h3>

      <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="footerContent"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="column column-2">
      <h3>Content2</h3>

      <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="footerContent"></textarea>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.column-1 {
  display: none;
}

.column-2 {
  display: none;
}
```

Jquery

```
 $('[name=footerLayout]').click(function() {
      var selector = ".column-" + $(this).val(); //Create selector        
      $(".column").not(selector).hide(); //Hide others        
      $(selector).show(); //Show column based on selected value
    });
```

If i click on an option from the select tag it doesn't show the hidden div right away. I would have to click it 2 times in order for it to work.

try it yourself:

https://jsfiddle.net/mk425srx/

Notice you must click the option 2 times for it to work, I want this to be 1 time. It has to change directly. How do i achieve this. 
EDIT
Its working fine in firefox and chrome 53 apparently its a chrome 54 issue..

Comment: Works fine here

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show hidden field on option click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256366/show-hidden-field-on-option-click)

Comment: Which browser @Morpheus

Comment: it works fine, I am using firefox 49

Comment: Works fine for me too VtC

Comment: On click of select you want the hidden div to show up or on change of the select (as in selecting column 1 and column 2) ?

As on change I see the Hidden divs which means 2 clicks

Comment: @Kevin Aartsen Chrome version 53

Comment: instead of click use change  $("...").on("change"

Comment: Works fine here.  Chrome 54.

Comment: This is  so strange @HaukurHaf

Comment: What device, browser, version are you on?

Comment: @AllDani 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit) on a mac OSX yosemite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `change` event instead of `click`

Just change the event in your JS. The updated code looks like

```
$('[name=footerLayout]').change(function() {
  var selector = ".column-" + $(this).val(); //Create selector        
  $(".column").not(selector).hide(); //Hide others        
  $(selector).show(); //Show column based on selected value
});
```

See the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mk425srx/2/

**Update**

The reason of `click` event not working as expected is because of, `click` event get fired when the element is *clicked* but `change` event is fired after the value get *changed*. So `click` event is fired earlier and before the value selection is changed. That's why `click` event shouldn't be used to detect change of value.

To be clear about this, try the following code to see the fact.

```
$('[name=footerLayout]').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});

$('[name=footerLayout]').click(function() {
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/mk425srx/3/

Comment: Well this works but i'm still so curious what is causing this problem, thanks!